# Adobe Flash Player plugin for firefox

Tags: firefox, plugins, server

I seek to install the Adobe Flash Player plugin on firefox 39.0 for all users of my terminal server.

I've found so many solutions on the internet all of which do not work (yay). So can someone explain to me one working solution to get the latest Adobe Flash Player on the firefox 39.0 of all my users, so they will be able to see flash? I'd rather do stuff in `Program Files (x86)/Mozilla Firefox/browser` than in everyone's `Users/user1/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla`.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For other plugins, this used to work:
http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/windows-7/install-firefox-flash-plugin-manually-on-windows-7/

In case of Adobe Flash Player, I could not find an `.xpi` file, instead it worked this way:

1. log in on terminal server as local administrator
2. go to command line and type `change user /install`
3. install from https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/ (unchecking McAfee)
4. go to command line and type `change user /execute`

And it appeared to be installed for all users; solved. So no manually messing around with files here.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently Firefox now blocks versions of flash older than  18.0.0.209, so check you've got that, or else try to unblock it manually.

Source: http://gizmodo.com/firefox-now-blocks-flash-by-default-1717664482

Comment: So is there any way I could get my hands on a good `.xpi` file of flash which will do the job (allowing my clients to see flash), thus adobe flash player 18.0.0.209 or newer?

Comment: I've got it now for myself but want to have it for all clients of a server.
(no firefox veteran, so: (option a) I do know how to do it IF I have an `.xpi` or (option b) you show me some other way to do it)

Comment: If you've installed it for your profile [look here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox), use the file path to the .xpi for the following command:

"firefox -install-global-extension /path/to/extension"    

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-install-global-extension_.2Fpath.2Fto.2Fextension)